# why i cant create user and no do i gets any error in django?

Tags: python, django

when i  am trying to create a user , it does not shows any message/error nor its creating a user , please help me .(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKhMf.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx7bt.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3svX.jpg)

***views.py***

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'post':
    username = request.post('username')
    email = request.post('email')
    password = request.post('password')
    password2 = request.post('password2')
    if password == password2:
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.info(request,'email already exist')
            return redirect('register')
        elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.info(request,'username already exists')
            return redirect('register')
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, 
 email=email, password=password)
            user.save();
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        messages.info(request,'password does not match')
        return redirect('register')
else:
    return render(request, 'register.html')
```

*register.html*

```
<h1>sign up here</h1>

{% for message in messags %}
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
{% endfor %}

<form method="POST" action ="register">
{% csrf_token %}
<p>username:</p>
<input type="text" name="username" />
<p> email:</p>
<input type="email" name="email"/>
<p>password:</p>
<input type="password" />
<p> repeat password:</p>
<input type="password" name="password2" /><br>

<input type="submit" />



</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('counter', views.counter, name='counter'),
path('register', views.register, name='register')
]
```

**i should have been able to create new user but **

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: hey , i included the codes too

Comment: any Error or getting redirected to `Register` again instead `login`?

Comment: yeah i gets redirected to register again and does not gets any message even when i am using the same username which already exist in db and when adding new data ,it does not add in db , redirects to the register

Answer (score 0):

Change the `request.post('')` to `request.POST['']`

Change the view to :

```
def register(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      username = request.POST['username']
      email = request.POST['email']
      password = request.POST['password']
      password2 = request.POST['password2']
      if password == password2:
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
           messages.info(request,'email already exist')
           return redirect('register')
        elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
           messages.info(request,'username already exists')
           return redirect('register')
        else:
           user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
           user.save();
           return redirect('login')
     else:
       messages.info(request,'password does not match')
       return redirect('register')
else:
  return render(request, 'register.html')
```

Change Your HTML to this

```
<h1>sign up here</h1>

{% for message in messags %}
   <h1>{{message}}</h1>
{% endfor %}

<form method="POST" action ="register">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <p>username:</p>
   <input type="text" name="username" />
   <p> email:</p>
   <input type="email" name="email"/>
   <p>password:</p>
   <input type="password" name="password" />
   <p> repeat password:</p>
   <input type="password" name="password2" /><br>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: now i am getting MultiValueDictKeyError

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the error here